# Excel VBA Write unique values from one table to another

Tags: excel, vba

So I have a fairly basic excel spread sheet where I track orders.
I want too create a dashboard sheet that gives me information on my orders and products but am running into difficulty.

My Orders table is as follows.

```
Order_ID , Product_Name, Purchased_With, Order_Type, Price, Amount_Purchased, Amount_Paid, Order_Status.
```

I would like my dashboard to be as follows.

```
Product, Total_Invested, Total_Sold, ROI, Value.
```

In my dash board too I would like to be able to get specific stats on my products like my average buy and whatnot.

I am running into difficulty getting the unique products into my dashboard table.
I would also like to do the programming all in excel but I think I may have to write a python application but would like to know if this is possible.

I would like something like this.

```
Products = orders_table.Product_Name.Unique
Products.WriteTo(Dashboard_Table.Product)
Return
```

Is this possible at all in just excel? Any help would be greatly appreciated as I find the documentation rather unhelpful.

Comment: Have you had a look to Pivot tables?

Comment: @FunThomas That's exactly what I need thank you so much! I didn't know about them